# ESLint with Airbnb-base using Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, eslint

So I am trying to add the Airbnb style guide to my company's code base using ESLint and Gulp. I'm running into the following error:

```
Error: Failed to load plugin import: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-import'
Referenced from: airbnb-base
Referenced from: 
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
```

Here is my current configuration:

`eslint.gulp.js`

```
export default (gulp, plugins, config) => {
return gulp.src([
  `${config.SRC}/**/*.js`,
  `!${config.SRC}/**/__generated/*.js`,
  `!${config.SRC}/libraries/**`,
  `!**/node_modules/**`
])
.pipe(plugins.errorHandler())
.pipe(plugins.eslint({
  "extends": "airbnb-base"
})
)
.pipe(plugins.eslint.format())
.pipe(plugins.eslint.failAfterError());
}
```

`.eslintrc file`

```
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true
  },
  "extends": "airbnb-base",
  "rules": {}
}
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest

- `npm install npm@latest -g`
- `rm -rf node_modules`
- `npm install`

Comment: Yeah it's there, but I think it is a reference issue

Comment: check ur npm version if its defined as a peerDependency the onlder version of npm wont be able to install it properly. i suggest update npm remove node_modules reinstall